# Where to put "delete" in the loop

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Suppose I have the following code:

```
int decreasingTest(int number){
int numberOfDigits = 0; do { number /= 10; numberOfDigits++; } while (number != 0);
int *arrayValue = new int[numberOfDigits + 1];
for(int i = numberOfDigits;0<=i;i--){ //acquire digits of number
    arrayValue[i] = (number - fmod(number, pow(10, i))) / pow(10, i);
    number = fmod(number, pow(10, i));
    i--;
}
for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfArray; j++){
    if (arrayValue[j + 1] <= arrayValue[j]){
        if ((j + 1) == sizeOfArray){
            cout << "The number's digits are decreasing." << endl;
            return 5;
        }
        continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Should I put `delete arrayValue[]` in the line before `return 0` and after the bracket after `continue`, after the line `return 0`, or on the line before the last bracket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three places in your code where you might return from the function:

1. on the `return 5` line
2. on the `return 0` line, after the loop
3. Before the closing brace, if the outer loop never executes.

In order to not leak resources, there must be one `delete` call executed for every `new` call executed. In your case, since you have two return points, you need two `delete` calls -- one just before each of the return points.

Manually managing dynamic memory as you're doing here is problematic.  It's very easy to forget to delete something, especially when you have multiple return points.  Many language features and library components have been built to solve this problem.  Smart pointers like [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) manage the destruction of dynamically-allocated resources automatically so you don't need to write `delete` at all, and `make_shared` and `make_unique` enable you to never even write `new`.  (Note: `make_unique` isn't in the C++11 Standard, but it's easy to write, and it is expected to be in the C++14 Standard.)

C-Style arrays are also problematic in their own right for a number of reasons.  One of the most obvious is their fixed-size and the magic numbers that often come with them.  Language features and library components exist to solve this problems as well, and I'd suggest that as a rule, you should (almost) never use C-style arrays.  Instead, use a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

In your case, you don't need pointers at all.  You just need a `vector':

```
std::vector <int> arrayValue;
for(int i = numberOfDigits;0<=i;i--){ //acquire digits of number
    arrayValue.push_front(number - fmod (number, pow(10, i))) / pow(10,i);
    //arrayValue[i] = (number - fmod(number, pow(10, i))) / pow(10, i);
    number = fmod(number, pow(10, i));
    i--;
}

...
```

Answer (score 4):

For this particular case, there is no reason to use dynamic memory. Not trying to be pedantic, but dynamic memory gets used lots of places it should not be.

[ADDENDUM (further information and shameless grab for possible points)]

You'd think the needed number of digits would already be in a standard library, since decimal representation is so common. The following is based on a posting by Hallvard Furuseth in Google Group comp.std.c, but I do not deduct the sign bit from the initial bit-size count, so it should work for both signed and unsigned types. The +3 term is for the digit needed to store factor '1' (log10(1)=0); for the sign '+' or '-'; and for a possible null termination character. The factor of 146/485 is only slightly greater than log10(2) (equivalently log(2)/log(10) in any base), which is the digit scaling factor from binary to decimal representation. Please let me know if you spot any problems.

```
//Overestimate for number of decimal digits representing an integer of type integerType
//Works for both signed and unsigned integer types
//Includes space for sign ('+' or '-') and for a termination character
//Upper-bounds the function floor(log10(abs(n))) + 3

#define SIZEDIGITS(integerType) (((sizeof(integerType)*CHAR_BIT)*146)/485 + 3)
```

int8_t:
5 digits ('+/-127\0')

uint8_t:
5 digits ('+255\0')

APPROXIMATION gives (8*146)/485 + 3 = 5 digits

int16_t:
7 digits ('+/-32767\0')

uint16_t:
7 digits ('+65536\0')

APPROXIMATION gives (16*146)/485 + 3 = 7 digits

int32_t:
12 digits ('+/-2147483647\0')

uint32_t:
12 digits ('+4294967295\0')

APPROXIMATION gives (32*146)/485 + 3 = 12 digits

int64_t:
21 digits ('+/-9223372036854775807\0')

uint64_t:
22 digits ('+18446744073709551615\0')

APPROXIMATION gives (64*146)/485 + 3 = 22 digits

int128_t:
41 digits

uint128_t:
41 digits

APPROXIMATION gives (128*146)/485 + 3 = 41 digits

int9999_t (pretend): 3012 digits

uint9999_t (pretend): 3012 digits

APPROXIMATION gives (9999*146)/485 + 3 = 3013 (an unused byte - the humanity!)

(Random bonus fact you may or may not be aware of: base-e is considered the most efficient real-number base in terms of our usual sum-of-powers digit representation for real numbers. Ternary outperforms binary in this respect, since it's closer to e.)

Comment: Where do I put the 'delete'? 'Nowhere' is an answer, and it would seem the correct one. This is a very common problem, that someone asks where do I put the delete, when they didn't need a new in the first place. In the future I will try to get clarification on possible XY questions.

Comment: I disagree with the accepted answer, which states that a vector is needed in this case.

Comment: @dwn Because the number of digits is based on the `number` parameter, dynamic memory *must* be used. My understanding of your answer disregards that. If you were simply debating whether the programmer should manage dynamic memory, or `std::vector`/`std::unique_ptr` should manage it. I agree with what you are trying to communicate that generally the programmer managing memory is bad. But I have no idea why you' favor an auto-pointer to a dynamic array over a `std::vector`.

Comment: INT_MAX is known in advance, so it is easy to derive CEIL_LOG10_INT_MAX in advance, and then MAXDIGITS = CEIL_LOG10_INT_MAX + 1 (if counting negative sign as a digit)

Comment: Just found a discussion on this same issue, which saves any predefinitions by using a "crude but effective" upper bound of '(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) + 5)/3': https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/WhJvpeHeCro

Comment: @dwn that's actually a really good point. I'd vote for an answer that pointed that out.

Answer (score 2):

Given the code structure you have now, there are three separate places that you would need to put your `delete [] arrayValue;` command (note, the `[]` is before `arrayValue`, not after it). You would need to put it on the line right above `return 5;`, on the line right above `return 0;`, and right before the last bracket. It is possible that the code exits your function on any of those three lines, and, in this case, you should deallocate your memory right before you exit the function.

Alternatively, you could just replace the line `int *arrayValue = new int[numberOfDigits + 1];` with `std::vector<int> arrayValue(numberOfDigits + 1)`, and let the compiler handle the allocation/deallocation for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use a smart pointer, for example std::unique_ptr (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which automatically frees the dynamically allocated array when the pointer goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

1. The most important point is that there is almost never a case in which you should `new` an array anymore. I would strongly suggest that you use a `std::vector` here, so your `int *arrayValue = new int[numberOfDigits + 1];` would become: **`std::vector<int> arrayValue(numberOfDigits + 1);`** And you're done no other code changes needed.
   Note that in situations where the code can error, say one of your `pow`s throws for instance and you leave this function without returning, `std::vector` still cleans itself up, something that cannot be said of `new`ed memory.
2. If you find yourself in the 1% of situations where you should manage your own memory. A good rule of thumb is *never* have more than one return statement. It simply makes your code unreadable and unmaintainable. So you should change your last loop to:

   `int result = 0;`
   `int j = 0;`

   `while(j < sizeOfArray - 1 && arrayValue[j + 1] <= arrayValue[j]){`
   `j++;`
   `}`

   `if (j == sizeOfArray - 1){`
   `cout << "The number's digits are decreasing." << endl;`
   `result = 5;`
   `}`
   `delete[] arrayValue;`
   `return result;`

Comment: Can't I just use `vector <int> arrayValue` instead of declaring its size?

Comment: @DonLarynx You can, **but** you will need to `push_back` any value that is added to the `std::vector` and `std::vector` will reallocate space to accommodate. Because you know the size up front it's far faster to pass a size to the `std::vector` constructor because then only one allocation is made. Of course these values will be uninitialized just as if you had used a `new` so even though they are allocated you'll have to fill the `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

It is the case when you should use standard smart pointer `std::unique_ptr` declared in header `<memory>`. For example

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arrayValue( new int[numberOfDigits + 1] );
```

In this case you need not to bother about deleting the array.